# Splitting a long string with Python

Tags: python, string, split

Say that I have a long string (as an input from a txt file) that contains terms like `2*log(y) + 5*x + z3 -65./5.*y + ...` and I want to split it using a Python script and write it into a new file. My problem is that I want every 72 characters, to start "looking" for the next `+` and at this point to do the splitting. FYI, this expression is meant to be an input to 
a C code.

Comment: Sample Test case

Answer (score -1):

Here `f[::72]` will give every 72 characters from the file and splitted and write to a file `f2`

```
 f=open('f.txt').read()
    f2=open('f2.txt','w')
    for i in f[::72]:
        print(i.split('+'),file=f2)
```

Comment: please write some explanation along with the code. code only answers are generally discouraged in SO --Review